# Why do we need the create and construct functions

Tags: javascript

Why is it useful to have these two functions, create and construct

```
if (!Object.create) {
  Object.create = function(base) {
    function F() {};
    F.prototype = base;
    return new F();
  }
}

if (!Object.construct) {
  Object.construct = function(base) {
    var instance = Object.create(base);
    if (instance.initialize)
      instance.initialize.apply(instance, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: Whoever said "we need the create and construct functions" and who is "we"?

Answer (score 1):

[Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) was introduced in JavaScript 1.8.5 only and it allows to create a new object with a specified prototype and a set of properties. The reason you might want the code you posted is to polyfill the function in old browsers that don't support `Object.create`. However, be careful, because the polyfill implementation only support the first argument.

Here's how you could use it:

```
var parentObject = { name: 'test' },
    childObject = Object.create(parentObject);

console.log(childObject.name); // -> test
```

As for `Object.construct`, I did not found any reference to this function in the  specification, but from what I can see, it does the same thing as `Object.create`, but additionnaly, it will call the `initialize` function of the `base` object in the context of the newly created object and will pass to it additionnal parameters that you might have passed after the `base` param.

For example:

```
var parentObject = {
    initialize: function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
};

var childObject = Object.construct(parentObject, 'test');

console.log(childObject.name); // -> test
```

Answer (score 0):

"we" don't.  `Object.create` is a way to create objects with very low-level access to the object in modern browsers (those that run this portion of ES5 to spec).

```
var bob = Object.create(Person.prototype, { name : {
                                                writeable : false,
                                                configurable : false,
                                                value : "Bob"          }});
```

`bob` inherits from `Person`.

`bob.name` now equals "Bob".
`bob.name` can not be rewritten.
`bob.name` can not be changed to a different data-type (number/boolean/NaN/null/etc).
`bob.name` can not be deleted, except, perhaps, by getting rid of `bob`, completely.

This will only work in modern browsers.

The `Object.create` polyfill only does the inheritance part, because old versions of JavaScript didn't allow access to an object's enumerables, or whether they were writeable or type-specific, et cetera.
Therefore, they can not be polyfilled in.

Nobody ***needs*** `Object.create`.  Nobody who isn't doing systems-architecture (be it AJAX-libraries or a new NodeJS-based banking system or cloud-OS or whatever), that is.  Even then, it's only useful if you can guarantee that the browser is using a modern version of JS.